# How do i add custom fields to Devise-invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have generated the view with `rails generate devise_invitable:views`
I have also edited the generated views in users/invitations/new.html.erb to include the fields I want to include first name and last name

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: invitation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "users/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label field %><br />
      <%= f.text_field field %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label field %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :fist_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label field %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have added this line of code  `# devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'users/invitations' }` to the `routes.rb` file

I alse created a controller to inherit the Devise controller

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
    def update
      if some_condition
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def create
        
    end

    def new
        
    end
  end
```

yet still, when I go to the `new_user_invitation_path` to make an invite I get only the email field. please how do I make custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've added the `first_name` and `last_name` fields to your user's table.

**Permitting Custom Fields:**

In your `application_controller.rb`, permit custom fields when accepting an invitation.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :accept_invitation, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email]
end
```

This step ensures that the custom fields `:first_name` and `:last_name` are permitted when a user accepts an invitation.

**Invitations Controller:**

In your `invitations_controller.rb` add a `before_action` hook to call `configure_permitted_parameters`.

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:invite, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

In the controller, we are permitting the custom fields `:first_name` and `:last_name` when inviting a user. This ensures that the values entered in the form are accepted when sending an invitation.

**Invitation Instructions Email Template:**

In the `invitation_instructions.html.erb` template include the first name and last name of the invited user.

```
<p>
  <strong><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.first_name") %>:</strong> <%= @resource.first_name %> 
  <strong><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.last_name") %>:</strong> <%= @resource.last_name %>
</p>
```

--> **Skip this if you already have some User Mailer**

**User Model:**
Define an `after_create` callback named eg `send_admin_mail`. This callback method is automatically triggered after a new user is created.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :send_admin_mail

  def send_admin_mail
    SomeMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_later
  end
end
```

Within the send_admin_mail method, after sending you call `UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver` to send a welcome email to the newly registered user. Here, `self` refers to the instance of the user that triggered the `after_create` callback.

By invoking `UserMailer.welcome_email(self)`, you're passing the user instance to the `welcome_email` method in the `UserMailer` class, which then uses the user's information to construct and send a personalized welcome email.

**User Mailer:**
Assuming you have some Mailer working located in `app/mailers/some_mailer.rb` that defines an email template for sending emails to users. Make sure you are using `ApplicationMailer` as the base class for your mailer, as shown in this example:

```
class SomeMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "https://sitename.com/"

    subject = "Welcome, #{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}"
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

--> **Skip End**

To test sending an invitation to a user, use the invite! class method.

```
rails c

User.invite!(email: 'new_user@example.com', name: 'John Doe')
# => an invitation email will be sent to new_user@example.com
```

If you have the [letter_opener_web](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web) gem installed and setup, after sending the email the template will open in your browser interface automatically.

If you run into issues with the above check the [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#strong-parameters-).